# Please tell why two references are same for string object in case of string( Code written below)

Tags: .net, string, comparison

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class ddLlSTeXPT : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          string pass="infoways";

          if(txtbx.Text==pass)
          Response.Write("hello U Logged In");
          else
          Response.Write("hello U cant log In");
    }
}
```

But it print correctly if the text in textbox is "infoways". How thesepoint to same refrence as the two objects are assigned different memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. The code that you've posted tests to see if the text in the `TextBox` control is equivalent to the string "infoways". If so, it displays the message "hello U Logged In"; if not, it displays the message "hello U can't log In". Your code appears to be working as expected.

The `==` operator is overloaded for the `String` class, so when you write `string1 == string2`, that is essentially equivalent to `String.Equals(string1, string2)`. Unlike other objects, the `==` operator does not compare reference equality for `String` types. As explained by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

> Although string is a reference type,
>   the equality operators (== and !=) are
>   defined to compare the values of
>   string objects, not references. This
>   makes testing for string equality more
>   intuitive.

Comment: Thanks Gray i was thinking it to be Reference equivalence rather It as Equals method checking as in Java.

Comment: @jagdeep: The `String` is treated as a special case in C#. Even though it's technically a reference type, most users will want to treat it like a value type, and so the `==` operator is overloaded to allow that. I don't know Java at all, but from the code you posted, it appears that what I described was the behavior you expected. Either way, I'm glad that my answer was helpful. Generally on Stack Overflow, you vote up all the answers you think were good, and accept (by clicking the checkmark outline in the left margin) the one you found most helpful.